# In bbpress notification email not sending for subscription users

Tags: wordpress

I have created a new topic using bbpress and also enabled the "Notify me of follow-up replies via email" option. 
If new user post the any reply means i did not receive the notification mail from them.

Comment: Need more details. Not enough to check. Please provide some code / integrations / html here.

Comment: I have implemented the forum site using bbpress plugin
Use below steps: 
 1. I have created a new forum topic and enabled the "Notify me of follow-up replies via email" and post the topics
 2. If new users come and post the reply for the question 
 3. The notification mail should send to forum topic created user 
 4. But the mail goes to replied user Instead of forum topic created user

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on BBForum , I suggest you to use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/asyncronous-bbpress-subscriptions/)  to fix the issue.

By default , the plugin

1. Sends mails from "MyBlog " (with your Blog’s name and admin email)
2. Sends mail to "Markus " (with the name being the user’s display name on the forums, not their username)